# d3.js dynamic data from database

Tags: database, d3.js

So, I wanan generate a `treemap` from `d3.js`.

The treemap needs data from a `json` file, the data of the json file comes from database(e.g. SQLite). I got so many users in my database, and every user has his/her own treemap.

How can I display treemap for different users when they request for the server?

Do I have to generate json file for every body(every one has his/her json file named after his/her name)? I'm just confused. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you want a JSON file for every treemap. You could of course generate that dynamically and make a call to whatever generates it with the user ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically generate the JSON data and return it to the user using PHP for example. When the user goes to the "treemap" page, you use their username as a parameter in your database which will return JSON data. You shouldn't need to store a JSON file on the server for each individual user.